# microsoft cloud App service and (google) cloud IOT Core Certificates

Tags: cloud, mqtt, azure-app-service-envrmnt, google-cloud-iot

I'll make it quick. I'm working at a startup, and we want to use IOT device using mqtt protocol.

Actually we have already a website and an API on a microsoft cloud.
But we are not happy about their IOT's solution (cost too heavy).
That's why We want to use a second cloud just for manage thoses IOT device.
Cloud IOT Core seems a good alternative.

How can I connect my c# API (microsoft App service) to google's Cloud IOT core and manage certificate on it.
(my purpose is that Google Cloud should only manage Mqtt's device and data).

Should I go for a function on google cloud who will automaticly create/manage certificate ? 
And then call it from my API ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think, connect with GCP IoT Core using MQTT. GCP IoT Core makes broadcast pubsub. Your c# api listen to pubsub using api services.

Your Architecture

IoT Device => IoT Core(MQTT) => PubSub (connect with api) => c# services

Answer (score 0):

[Google provides .NET samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/tree/master/iot/api) that you should get you started with getting your device connected to Google Cloud IoT Core. Of particular interest for connecting a device is [the MQTT example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/tree/master/iot/api/CloudIotMqttExample).